# How does polling with thread.sleep() work?

Tags: java, multithreading, polling

I am new to threads in Java, I am trying to understand how they work; considering the following code:

```
public class ZooInfo {
private static int counter = 0;

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {    

    new Thread(() -> {
        for(int i=0; i<500; i++) ZooInfo.counter++;
        }).start();
    
    while(ZooInfo.counter<100) {
        System.out.println("Not reached yet");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Reached!");
}   
}
```

The output of the above code:

```
Not reached yet
Reached!
```

I don't understand why the output prints "Not reached yet" just once, and not for every time counter is less than a 100. I was expecting the output to print "Not reached yet" a 100 then print "Reached"?

Comment: After the first "Not reached yet", your main thread sleeps for 1 second. By that time, the counter increased to > 100 and your condition in your loop is false.

Comment: because `Thread.sleep(1000);` is in your while loop so i think your program wait and after that your while condition is not true

Comment: But even without the thread.sleep(1000) the code still prints "Not reached yet" once.....

Comment: I wouldn't even be surprised if there are runs where "Not reached yet" isn't printed, at all. Especially if you add another IO operation before the while loop, the show is over before it begins.

Comment: @Polygnome well the first check will be done before the (expensive) I/O operations, so I would expect it to print at least once given the value for the `while` loop is high enough to be entered.

Comment: @Turing85 Since thread scheduling is discretionary, there is no reason why the main thread couldn't be suspended for whatever reason after starting the second thread and only resume when the second thread is done. I don't expect that to happen often, but I wouldn't be surprised if it did happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I don't understand why the output prints "Not reached yet" just once, and not for every time counter is less than a 100.*" - It does! The value of `ZooInfo.counter`, however, is only checked once a second. The thread started (`new Thread(() -> { for(int i=0; i<500; i++) ZooInfo.counter++; }).start();` will take significantly less than a second for the first 100 iterations. Removing the `Thread.sleep(...)` does not necessarily change the behaviour (for me, it leads to `Not yet reached!` being printend 1-3 times). This is due to the fact that the newly created thread still has a head start. Also, the two threads do not run "in unison", i.e. one thread may proceed faster or slower than the other.

Furthermore, as was pointed out by [@Amongalen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045252/how-does-polling-with-thread-sleep-work/64045350#comment113253283_64045350) and [@Polygnome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045252/how-does-polling-with-thread-sleep-work/64045350#comment113253680_64045252), printing to `System.out` is slow. We can improve this by using a `StringBuilder`:

```
final String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) ZooInfo.counter++;
}).start();

final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (ZooInfo.counter < 100) {
    builder.append("Not reached yet").append(lineSeparator);
}

builder.append("Reached!");
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

This will increase the number of times `Not reached yet!` is printed.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3AW9pi)

---

A remark: the field `private static int counter = 0;` should also be declared `volatile` to guarantee proper visibility between threads.

Comment: even if you remove `Thread.sleep(1000)` or modify the while and for loop condition to a bigger number(2000), it prints `Not reached yet` only once.

Comment: Not necessarily. For me, it prints one to three times.

Comment: @Turing85 even without the  `thread.sleep(1000)` the output still prints `Not reached yet` once..

Comment: Again: this is not necessarily true; for me it prints 1-3 times. I updated my answer to give an explanation for the effect.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that `System.out.println()` takes really long time compared to variable incrementation. That is why it prints only once even if you remove `thread.sleep()`. In my case I had to increase count up to 10000 for it to print multiple times.

Comment: @Turing85 so does this mean each i has its own thread? What do you mean by "the newly created thread has a head start" and by "the two threads do not run "in unison""? I thought there is only one thread created...

Comment: @san you start with the initial thread (the one exeucting your program) and create and start one additional thread (by calling `new Thread(...).start();`. The first loop runs the "new" thread, the second loop runs in the "old" thread. --- "*the two threads do not run "in unison", i.e. **one thread may proceed faster or slower than the other***"